# Google OAuth2 Service API: Issue fetching access token using service email and private key

Tags: google-oauth

Tried fetching the access token using JWT as well as Java Auth client API call but did not succeed.

Using Java client API code below , I get Exception "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out".

```
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId("@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("<publickey>-privatekey.p12"))
        .setServiceAccountScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control")
        .build();
        credential.refreshToken();
        System.out.println("access token : " + credential.getAccessToken());
        System.out.println("refresh token : " + credential.getRefreshToken());
```

If we remove call to "credential.refreshtoken()", it returns null access key and refresh key. Could someone please guide me and tell where I am going wrong?

Also using direct JWT token for authentication as listed below, I get response "{"error" : "invalid_grant"}" with Error code 400 :

```
  private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String keyFile, String alias, String password)
            throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException
          {
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keystore.load(new FileInputStream(keyFile), password.toCharArray());
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());

            return privateKey;
          }

  public static String sign(PrivateKey privateKey, JsonFactory jsonFactory,
          String header, String payload) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("header : " + header +  " : " + Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(header.getBytes())); 

        System.out.println("payload : " + payload +  " : "  + Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(payload.getBytes()));

        String content = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(header.getBytes()) + "."
                    + Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(payload.getBytes());
        byte[] contentBytes = StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(content);
        Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signer.initSign(privateKey);
        signer.update(contentBytes);
        byte[] signature = signer.sign();
        String signedContent = content + "." + Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(signature);
        System.out.println("signedContent:" + signedContent);
        return signedContent;
      }


public static void main(String args[]) {
        HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
        String header = "{\"alg\":\"RS256\",\"typ\":\"JWT\"} ";
        String payload = "{\"iss\":\"*******@developer.gserviceaccount.com\",\"scope\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control\",\"aud\":\"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token\",\"exp\": " + new Date().getTime() + ",\"iat\":" + (new Date().getTime() + 3600000) + "}";

         PrivateKey serviceAccountPrivateKey = getPrivateKey("<public_key>-privatekey.p12", "privatekey", "notasecret");
            String assertion = sign(serviceAccountPrivateKey, JSON_FACTORY, header, payload);   


    }
```

Later passing this assertion to API "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" with this generated assertion and grant type "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" , gives response "{"error" : "invalid_grant"}" with Error code 400.

Could someone please help me and suggest where I am going wrong?